# My code gets disrupted when you hover over a dropdown list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I've made a full width menu container that drops down when you hover the button "Content Overview" (pink button on the  top right).

In the container I have a WordPress categories Widget with a dropdown.

The problem is that when you click and open the dropdown list, and you hover over a list item, the menu container closes immediately.

http://www.webmotus.com/

I have no clue what causes this, other than when you hover a category list item, it disrupts the code and closes the container.

I made a Fiddle to showcase the code & HTML working http://jsfiddle.net/62erLe6y/

```
var upTimer = false ,
downTimer = false ,
isHover = false ;

$(".carbsanity-custom-menu-trigger, 
.carbsanity-custom-menu-container").hover(function(){
isHover = true;
clearTimeout(upTimer);

downTimer = setTimeout(function(){
    if(isHover)
    $(".carbsanity-custom-menu-container").slideDown(500);
},500);

},function(){

isHover = false;
clearTimeout(downTimer);


upTimer = setTimeout(function(){
     $(".carbsanity-custom-menu-container").slideUp(500);
},100);

});
```

Can someone advice me on how to change my code so that it doesn't close my menu container?

Thank you :-)

Comment: Have you already fixed this? In Chrome and Safari the menu container does not close when hovering over a category list item

Comment: That's very odd, did you try to refresh the page and try once more? I've experienced that it didn't close like twice, but the last 20 attempts it closed immediately. I've tried in all browsers, it's the same everywhere.

Comment: Can someone else please try, maybe it's just my laptop, but tbh that would be odd.

Comment: Refreshed loads, still works fine every time

Comment: Ok I can see that it works in Firefox, but Chrome, Opera and Explorer it doesn't. Damn this is weird. Can someone else please try? :-)